# Xcode 6 3.5 inch screenshots

Tags: ios, xcode6, screenshot, simulator

I have developed an iOS app using Xcode 6 and am now ready to submit my app to iTunes connect but I need screenshots for a 3.5 inch device.

However there isn't a simulator for a device that has that screensize.

Can someone advise how to get the required screenshots which I believe need to be 640 x 960 pixels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iPhone 4S is such a device. If you don't see an iPhone 4S simulator, make one (in Window > Devices).

Comment: That spot on, thanks for your help (I thought the 4s was 4 inch as well)